# To define operator of closure, interior and cardinal

Tags: macros, math-operators

How can define math operator closure, interior and cardinal?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}


\begin{document}


$\bigskip IntA=clB$


$card\beta \mathbb{N}=card\beta \mathbb{Q}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am using Scientific workplace 5.5, when I define the math operator in this program, it defines it as \limfunc{***} as below. When I type this in preamble it doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\limfunc{Int}}{Int} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\limfunc{cl}}{cl}
\begin{document}
$\limfunc{Int}A=\limfunc{cl}A$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Look in the site for `\DeclareMathOperator`

Answer (score 2):

Here there are the three definition of Int, card, and cl using  `\DeclareMathOperator`. See the output of the screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Int}{Int}
\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}
\DeclareMathOperator{\clo}{cl}
\begin{document}


$\Int A =\{x\in B : x\leq 4\}$ (\verb|\DeclareMathOperator for Interior|)

Let $A=\{1,3,4,9\}$ i.e., the set of numbers $1,3,4$ and $9$, we see that there are $4$ elements in this set and therefore $\card(A)=4$.

(\verb|\DeclareMathOperator for cardinality|)

$\clo C= D\cup E$ (\verb|\DeclareMathOperator for closure|)

\end{document}
```

### Addendum

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\limfunca}{\operatorname{Int}}
\newcommand{\limfuncb}{\operatorname{cl}}

\begin{document} 
$\limfunca A=\limfuncb A$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using Scientific workplace 5.5, when I define the math operator in this program, it defines it as \limfunc{***} as below. When I type this in preamble it doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?
      \documentclass{article}
      \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
      \DeclareMathOperator{\limfunc{Int}}{Int}
      \DeclareMathOperator{\limfunc{cl}}{cl}
      \begin{document}
      $\limfunc{Int}A=\limfunc{cl}A$
      \end{document}

Comment: @MehmetOnat I have my doubts about whether it works with Scientific Workplace, which I used only a couple of times many, many years ago. Try the code I've entered for you.